# Grails hyphenated URL converter issue with default index method

Tags: grails

According to the Grails [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#customizingUrlFormat), the default URL mapping (between controller actions and URLs) uses camel case.  You can easily change the URL mapping to use hyphenated URLs:

```
grails.web.url.converter = 'hyphenated'
```

So for instance, HelloWorldController.showUsers would map to:

```
/hello-world/show-users
```

In Grails, you can have a default controller action which by convention is "index".  So for instance, if you have a method named index(), the following URL will hit that method:

```
/hello-world
```

You can create an anchor tag which links to that URL like this:

```
<g:link controller="HelloWorld">Go!</g:link>
```

I noticed a strange bug where if my controller name prefix is only one "word" such as HelloController, then:

```
<g:link controller="Hello">Go!</g:link>
```

... will always generate URLs which point to:

```
/hello/index
```

... instead of:

```
/hello
```

I refactored and renamed it to other single word controllers and the problem persisted.  I was using Grails 2.2.2 so I upgraded to Grails 2.3.4 and was surprised this bug still existed.  Renaming the controller to any two word prefix, like HomePageController, HelloWorldController, OneTwoController, etc, is a workaround for now.

This is my first time really using GSP.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should file a bug on jira.grails.org

Comment: Interestingly, the first hit when I search the grails Jira is a security bug which is triggered when "hyphenated" is enabled and the controller prefix contains "two" words: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-162

Comment: Opened a bug report here: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10969

Comment: In case anyone's interested, I see a security related JIRA item here for the hyphenated config option: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9693 - until this is resolved it looks like it's best not to use hyphenated URL converter and instead use UrlMappings.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are part of the user experience and should be clean, so the `index` problem is really annoying.

It's inconvenient, but you can eliminate the `index` part of the URL for single word controllers by mapping each page and omitting the action.

**grails-app/config/UrlMappings.groovy**

```
class UrlMappings {

   static mappings = {
      "/hello"     (controller: "hello")
      "/settings"  (controller: "settings")
      "/dashboard" (controller: "dashboard")
      ...
```

Comment: Just tested on Grails 3.0, and the above workaround still does the trick.