# set default render file to index.html in grails 3 when routing to a webapp folder

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I have an index.html page within webapp/test folder. If I go to path localhost:8080/test/index.html, the page renders but if I go to localhost:8080/test/ it gives me page not found error. What is the right way to achieve this? In my UrlMappings.groovy I have tried these flavors without any luck.

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        /* TRIED THESE 
        "/"(view: "/index.html")
        "/"(url: "/index.html")
         */
        "500"(view: '/error')
        "404"(view: '/notFound')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your **test** controller and put your HTML at `views/test/index.gsp` and then you can route to `localhost:8080/test/` using:

```
"/test" (controller: "test")
```

Without the above mapping instruction, Grails seems to default the **action** explicitly to `index` in the URL (related to hyphenation issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29737608).

Comment: Thanks for the update, this information is definitely helpful. But my scenario is such that I don't have a backing controller for the page. I am building an ember app and the compiled app just sits within webapp folder(the compiled app has index.html). So if my compiled app was in folder webapp/test/, then when my URL is localhost/test I wanted it to render the index.html by default as it should, but this was not happening, instead I had to type in full path localhost/test/index.html - I hope this clarifies my problem a bit more.

Comment: Deewendra Shrestha: Did you figure this out? I have the same requirement with an AngularJS app. My index.html sits in webapp folder.